# Telerik - RadWaitingBar DotsLine change dots color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, telerik, progress-bar

I am using Telerik `RadWaitingBar` control with style as `DotsLine` in C# WinForms application. There is no property in `RadWaitingBar` to change color of the moving dots. I want to change the color of moving dots to white. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/track-and-status-controls/waitingbar/customizing-appearance/accessing-and-customizing-elements) Telerik Documentation. There are various properties that you can play with. e.g. you can change the background color if your dots are not visible etc.

Comment: Thankyou for your support. When i click my `RadWaitingBar`, there is `WaitingBarSeparatoElement` but there is no `WaitingBarIndicatorElement`. Where is this `WaitingBarIndicatorElement` in Element hierarchy editor?

Comment: Have a look at the following link to understand the hierarchy 
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/track-and-status-controls/waitingbar/indicator-elements